ARIMA over-predicting first value
I'm having an issue understanding ARIMA's predict() in statsmodels. Here's an example dataset:
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcopeix/AppliedTimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/refs/heads/main/data/jj.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)[:60]
df = df.set_index('date')

fit = ARIMA(df, order=(2,0,0)).fit()

df['pred'] = fit.predict()

df.head()
            data      pred
date                      
1960-01-01  0.71  3.218801
1960-04-01  0.63  0.745162
1960-07-02  0.85  0.678675
1960-10-01  0.44  0.811431
1961-01-01  0.61  0.584120

It seems that the first value is way over-predicted. It also looks like the predictions have been shifted by one after the first value. That is, pred[i+1] matches the values of data[i] very well. I thought maybe this is due to differencing, but I explicitly instruct ARIMA not to do differencing (p,0,0).
